# Android : Show the service state in an activity with a textView

Tags: android, service, android-activity, bind

I would like to show the current state of my service in my activity. I have seen that the service could be bound with the activity for different actions but I just want to know if it's started or stopped.

My main Activity start and stop my service

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
```

In fact, my service is "STICKY" and do some stuffs in background.
I want the activity to display the state of the service in a text view (like "running" or "not running" and the second composant would be a button to start/stop the service. (With a label that change according to the state ("start service" / "stop service").

So what could be the best technical solution to implement that?

Thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ActivityManager.getRunningServices()`

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices%28int%29

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to implement a listener or something to have to data updated in live on my activity?

Comment: Not really. There isn't any event that is fired when a service is killed (that I know of). However, you could just have a method check the running services every X seconds in the background and update it if something changes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `ActivityManager`, not `PackageManager`. The link I provided was correct. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this.

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then, that means I need to refresh the label (service running or not) and the button (start/stop service) when activity resume. And reproduce the update every X seconds. I think it could works.

I was just expecting something more "live" and practicle but it does the trick.

Comment: Sure. The question is: why do you want to do this? Normally a user doesn't need to know whether a service is running or not. If an app wants to use a service, it just starts it (if it is already running, Android won't start another one). And services can control how they are started/stopped. If you need to be informed when a service goes away, you can bind to the service. In that case, you will be informed when the service is killed. However, it makes no sense to bind to a service if you aren't going to use it.

Comment: I will try to explain my idea. My service would backup a particular folder of my internal storage into my dropbox folder when there are changes. But I want to be able to stop and start the service manually from only ONE button in my activity (label of button changing between start upload / stop upload). And to finish, I want a text view in my activity that indicate if the upload service is activated or not. (service started / service stopped).

Comment: I thought to change the text view and the button label directly when I start or stop the service from my activity but the problem is that the system can stop my service and the activity will not be notified.

Comment: If your service and your activity are running in the same process, Android will only kill off your service if the app goes to the background. In this case, the activity will also be in the background and will also be killed off. If your activity is in the foreground, Android won't kill off the process (or the service).

Comment: So it's perfect for my case if I understand well ! I just need to update my labels and text on resume of my activity ! And last question: how do you know if your activity and service are running in the same process?

Comment: You can force an Android component to run in a specific process by specifying `android:process="..."` in the manifest definition for that component. By default **all components** of an application (services, broadcastreceivers, activities, content providers) **run in the same process**.